# Old bluetooth mouse isn't detected by built-in bluetooth

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth

I've pulled my favorite mouse out of the cupboard, the Microsoft Wireless Laser Mouse 8000, circa Sept 2006. It's a Bluetooth mouse, but when in pairing mode (red & green flashing) it isn't seen by my Surface Book.

I found an old Microsoft Wireless Transceiver thinking the Bluetooth stack might no longer be compatible. Windows recognized the transceiver and even the mouse, and both are seen in the Devices & Printers. The mouse however is not working.

I installed the Microsoft IntelliPoint software and the mouse is shown in the mouse properties. I bring up the Connect your mouse Wizard, both transceiver and mouse flash, but never pair. I've tried it on 3 computers.

Is there a way I can see the raw Bluetooth data from the mouse or other ways to pair it in Windows 10?